# How to make a MFC application to DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I am new to MFC programming. I have a very simple MFC application that shows a plain dialog. I want to make a DLL that do the same as this piece of code.

The working dialog code looks like this:

```
class MyForm : public CDialog
{
public:
    MyForm(CWnd* pParent = NULL) : CDialog(MyForm::IDD, pParent) {};
    enum { IDD = DIALOG1 }; 

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX) {    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX); };
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog()
    {
        CDialog::OnInitDialog();
        return true;
    }

public:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

//Actural App
class MyApp: public CWinApp
{
public: 
    MyApp() {};
    virtual BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        CWinApp::InitInstance();
        MyForm dlg;
        m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
        INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
        return false;
    }
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyForm, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

//start the app
MyApp theApp;
```

I use visual studio MFC DLL project to make a new DLL project. I make a separate *.h file to declare the dll class, and a *.cpp file to define the class.

This is the *.h file looks like:

```
//header file for dll project
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <afxwin.h>
#include "resource.h"   

class CMyDllApp : public CDialog
{
public:
    __declspec(dllexport) CMyDllApp();
    enum { IDD = DLL_Dialog };
protected:
    __declspec(dllexport) virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);
    __declspec(dllexport) virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();    
public:
    __declspec(dllexport) afx_msg void myFunction();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

//Actural App
class MyDllMain : public CWinApp
{
public:
    __declspec(dllexport) MyDllMain() {};
    __declspec(dllexport) virtual BOOL InitInstance();
};
```

Now I include the *.h file in my client application, but I don't know how to call the dll class correctly.

Even if I only include the *.h file and do not add any other code, the dialog of dll class just **replace** my client dialog, if have `MyDllMain theApp;` in the cpp file of dll project.

```
//in *.cpp of the dll project
...
MyDllMain theApp;
```

If I put this line in my client application, I just get a "Assertion Failed" error when running. 
But if I don't put the line `MyDllMain theApp;` in dll project, how can I call my dll class when I want?

Comment: you need to `dllexport` the class not the member functions

Comment: You need to create MFC extension DLL: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f7ck28.aspx

Comment: Your header file can be used to create the DLL only, since all members are declared `__declspec(dllexport)`. Client code would need a header file with `__declspec(dllimport)`. A word of warning: If this puzzles you already, you should not be using MFC at all. It is **way** too complex at the moment. Using MFC requires, that you have all bases covered.